# Transverse knots with knot types of strongly quasi-positive knots

Tags: knot-theory, contact-geometry, contact-topology

In 2008, [Etnyre and Van Horn-Morris](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.0758.pdf) proved that if $L$ is a fibered strongly quasi-positive link, there is a unique (up to transverse isotopy) transverse link with the knot type of $L$ in the standard tight contact structure of $S^3$ with maximal self-linking number.

What is known for (not necessarily fibered) strongly quasi-positive links? If $L$ is strongly quasi-positive, is there a classification of transverse links with the knot type of $L$, with maximal self-linking number? Any comments or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The twist knot $K_{-6} = m(7_2)$ is strongly quasipositive, not fibered, genus-1, and it's Legendrian non-simple; it has five Legendrian isotopy classes with Thurston-Bennequin number 1, rotation number 0. A good source of material for low-crossing knots is the [Legendrian knot atlas](https://services.math.duke.edu/~ng/atlas/), by Chongchitmate and Ng.

Legendrian twist knots have been classified by Etnyre, Ng, and Vértesi (J. Eur. Math. Soc. **15** (2013)). I doubt that there exists a classification for arbitrary strongly quasipositive knots.